# Php - Remove repeated words in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

Input: ball ball code

Output should be: ball code

Input: awycodeawy

Output should be: awycode

I tried these, but didn't work:

```
$q = preg_replace("/\s(\w+\s)\1/i", "$1", $q);
$q = preg_replace("/s(w+s)1/i", "$1", $q);
```

Comment: What should `aabaaabaabaaa` become?

Comment: regex does not retain state, right? so why would this be a pure regex solution? somebody?

Comment: @Kristian: They can. To some extend. In particular anything that just repeats or follows a pattern is well suited for pattern matching. http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: @Mark Byers "aabaaabaabaaa" should be "aababaaba". 2 or more chars is considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is positive lookahead base attempt on regex based solution to OP's problem.

```
$arr = array('ball ball code', 'abcabc bde bde', 'awycodeawy');
foreach($arr as $str)
   echo "'$str' => '" . preg_replace('/(\w{2,})(?=.*?\\1)\W*/', '', $str) ."'\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
'ball ball code' => 'ball code'
'abcabc bde bde' => 'abc bde'
'awycodeawy' => 'codeawy'
```

As you can for the input `'awycodeawy'` it makes it to `'codeawy'` instead of `'awycode'`. The reason is that it is possible to find a `variable length lookahead` something which is not possible for `lookbehind`.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how much system resources does this code use? Is it make sense it to use for a website that run this code 3 time per minute. (Forgive me for being a noob :))

Comment: @noarm: In the present form this code is not resource intensive however I think resource usage depends on the length of the input string. If your input string is huge then it can take a while to scan through all the string to find duplicate.

Comment: it is not recommended to use it for testing against user sentences. This could harm the original string.

Comment: @JuniorMayhé: Original string is just echoed here not being updated.

Comment: My mistake I meant if someone try to update the original string, which is a sentence, it would mess with the original. I see it is being echoed ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$q = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", $q);
```

Comment: "abcabc bde bde" becomes "abcabc bde". Can't it be "abc bde"?

Comment: @noarm You said you wanted repeated *words*, not repeated *parts* of words. If you want it to apply to parts, however, change the `\s+` in the middle to a `\s*`.

Comment: @anubhava It was never intended to. Trying to match occurrences later on like that is nearly impossible to do well with regex (without breaking other things, like making `book` into `bok`, or `mississippi` into `missippi`).

Comment: @Amber: Yes, that's the whole point. The way problem was stated by OP cannot be solved by a pure regex solution.

Comment: The OP gave some examples of what he wants. This answer doesn't work for the second example he gave: `awycodeawy` -> `awycode`.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible that the word needs to be 3 (or more) times in a row (instead of 2), before it is being replaced with one? Thanks!